# modding snap instals

Tags: snap, read-only

I am using version 20.04, I am trying to design a smart mirror using ubuntu. I used `sudo snap install` and installed MagicMirror. it's supposed to be open source and I want to modify the modules in the dir, but I'm locked out. the error message given to me is *Read-Only file system*.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to work with the source code and create a new snap. You cannot change a published snap as such.

You will need to download the source code of the application you want to modify, modify it, create binaries and package these binaries into a snap. The [snap documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs) contains information on how that works.